# firebase simple login tutorial missing user

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

Tutorial: http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/wBhtRLWHIR/6-authenticating-users-with-a-service

I'm following this tutorial and it seems like I'm losing my user as soon as they register.

Here is my auth.js factory:

```
'use strict';

app.factory('Auth', function($firebaseSimpleLogin, FIREBASE_URL, $rootScope){

    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);

    var auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref);

    var Auth = {
        register : function(user) {
            return auth.$createUser(user.email, user.password);
        },
        signedIn : function() {
            // PROBLEM: authUser is always null
            console.log(auth.user);
            return auth.user !== null;
        },
        logout : function () {
            auth.$logout();
        }
    };

    $rootScope.signedIn = function () {
        return Auth.signedIn();
    };

    return Auth;
});
```

Here is my auth.js controller:

```
'use strict';

app.controller('AuthCtrl', function($scope, $location, Auth){
    if (Auth.signedIn()) {
        $location.path('/');
    }

    $scope.register = function () {
        Auth.register($scope.user).then(function (authUser) {
            console.log(authUser);
            $location.path('/');
        });
    };
});
```

The console.log under signedIn in the factory is always null. Any idea where the disconnect is? The registration itself is working fine, and `authUser` is populated in the console.log in the controller when registering.

Comment: Could I provide any other info that would be helpful?

Comment: What version of angularFire is this? It looks like it's probably a version issue. For example, the latest angularFire does not automatically log in (as the thinkster tutorial shows).

Comment: I checked the bower.json file that was part of the tutorial and it says ~0.7.1 as the angularfire version. In the index.html it also looks like its including a simple-login from angularfire as well though firebase-simple-login.js

Comment: same issue here. Register does not log in automatically.

Comment: @Jamie.Good did you see my answer at the end? apparently the tutorial is just not up-to-date with the latest version of angularFire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very similar question that is further along in the tutorial :[can't show logout button after $createUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23107080/cant-show-logout-button-after-createuser)

In the answer I learned that angularfire used to automatically log the user in after it was created. Apparently now it no longer does that which is why the auth.user in signedIn was null.

Answer (score 2):

[The latest documentation for Angularfire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html#createuser-email-password-nologin) says that the `$createUser` method of `$firebaseSimpleLogin` returns a promise but it doesn't mention *any* parameters being passed to the `then` callback.

You can use the [$getCurrentUser](https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html#getcurrentuser) method to get the current user after the user registers.

The tutorial needs to be updated and you should *always* be checking the documentation for whatever libraries you're using yourself.

Your code for signedIn should look like this:

```
Auth.signedIn = function() {
    auth.$getCurrentUser().then(function(currentUser) {
        console.log(currentUser);
    }, function() {
        console.log('error');
    });
};
```

Comment: Cool, I think this is probably the issue. I notified them the tutorial was out of date but haven't heard back. Where would I add getCurrentUser to this example to get it working? Just replace the signedIn function with a call to it?

Comment: I modified your code slightly to directly replace `signedIn:' inside the Auth object, but I'm getting this, any ideas: `Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

Comment: @turbo2oh no idea, you'll have to post that as a separate question? I've never seen that before :S :S

Answer (score 0):

I am now doing the same tutorial. This code (in auth controller) worked for me:

```
    $scope.register = function () {
        Auth.register($scope.user).then(function (authUser) {
            console.log(authUser);
            Auth.login($scope.user);
            $location.path('/');
        });
    };
```

I'm a total n00b, but what (I think) this is doing is authenticating the user, then running a function that logs the user in right after. Logout button is now functioning as expected.